# Is there a way to open the LAST google Doc using GoogleScript?

Tags: google-sheets

In my current GoogleScript, I've got a specific string of text/data copying to a UNIQUE word document (set by date & time of creation).

Is there a way to open and view the last edited/created Google Doc using GoogleScript?

Ideally, I'd have this sequence at the end of the rest of my GoogleScript to launch & view the newly created document for convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script can't open files to be visualized on a web browser (client-side). It could open them only on the server-side.